# How to get thumbnail in python code in version 3.2.5 of sorl thumbnail?

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

The documentation of sorl thumbnail still refers to the `get_thumbnail` function, but this doesn't exist in v.3.2.5. (`cannot import name get_thumbnail`)

For the life of me, I can't find any reference to what this function was changed to, or how to generate a thumbnail in the python code of this version of sorl. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my particular case, I've used an ThumbnailField with `extra_thumbnails` defined:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # other kwargs omitted for clarity
    image = ThumbnailField(extra_thumbnails={
                           'inline_preview': {'size': (600,400)},
                           'small_thumb': {'size': (75,75), 'options':['crop', 'sharpen']})
```

The `image` field will have a dict of the images defined by the `extra_thumbnails` option as an attribute named, surprisingly, `extra_thumbails`:

```
somemodel_instance.image.extra_thumbnails['inline_preview']
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, a few weeks ago I discovered I actually solved this problem before and I even wrote a short [blog post](http://www.ironzebra.com/news/4/) about it without remembering, *- smacks head*. If it's only the URL you're after, you can do this:

```
from solr.thumbnail.main import DjangoThumbnail

img = imageObject # a normal image url returned from an ImageField
size = (100,100) # any tuple 
img_resize_url = unicode(DjangoThumbnail(img, size))
```

It's a bit hackish, but it's better than Chris's solution in the sense that you can call any thumbnail size, without needing to adapt the `extra_thumbnails` field. That being said, I do find his solution cleaner in the sense that there are no internal imports from sorl required, but both ways should work.